# Copy files from a hdfs folder to another hdfs location by filtering with modified date using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, hadoop

I have 1 year data in my hdfs location and i want to copy data for last  6 months into another hdfs location.
Is it possible to copy data only for 6 months directly from hdfs command or do we need to write shell script for copying data for last 6 months?

I have tried hdfs commands for performing this, but didn't work.

I tried with the below shell script and it was working fine till creating TempFile but throwing an error

```
$ sh scriptnew.sh
scriptnew.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

and script is not executed further.

Below is the shell script which i used.

```
#!/bin/bash
hdfs dfs -ls /hive/warehouse/data.db/all_history/ |awk 'BEGIN{ SIXMON=60*60*24*180; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$6" "$7"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-SIXMON; if(WHEN > DIFF){print $8}}' >> TempFile.txt
cat TempFile.txt |while read line
do
    echo $i
    hdfs dfs -cp -p $line /user/can_anns/all_history_copy/;
done
```

What might be the error and how to resolve this ?

Comment: I don't think HDFS has this facility. You may have to sort the files based on datetime and sort them and then copy based on the datetime, for which you may need to write a shell script. If you can post your shell script attempt you probably attract some traction to your question. If you're doing it in a HDFS location, better to have a Java code than shell script as it is native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copying 6 months files from a hdfs location to another we can use the below script.

script should be run from your local linux location.

```
#!/bin/bash
hdfs dfs -ls /hive/warehouse/data.db/all_history/ |awk 'BEGIN{ SIXMON=60*60*24*180; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$6" "$7"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-SIXMON; if(WHEN > DIFF){print $8}}' >> TempFile.txt
cat TempFile.txt |while read line
do
   echo $i
   hdfs dfs -cp -p $line /user/can_anns/all_history_copy/;
done
```

> > > Line 2 : We are copying list of files which are of max 180 days to a TempFile.
> > >       Then we iterate through this Temp file and if match is found then copy the file.

If you are writing the script from windows and copying to linux machine, sometimes it may not work showing syntax error. 
For avoiding the carriage return error, after copying the script to linux machine local path run the below command.  **sed -i 's/\r//'**
Then run the script >>> **sh FileName.sh**